# How to round a float to the nearest quarter

Tags: java, math, rounding

Sometimes I need to round a float to the nearest quarter and sometimes to the nearest half.

For the half I use

```
Math.round(myFloat*2)/2f
```

I can use

`Math.round(myFloat*4)/4f`.

but is there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All you need is:

```
Math.round(myFloat*4)/4f
```

Since a half is also two quarters this single equation will take care of your half-rounding as well. You don't need to do two different equations for half or quarter rounding.

Code Sample:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float coeff = 4f;
        System.out.println(Math.round(1.10*coeff)/coeff);
        System.out.println(Math.round(1.20*coeff)/coeff);
        System.out.println(Math.round(1.33*coeff)/coeff);
        System.out.println(Math.round(1.44*coeff)/coeff);
        System.out.println(Math.round(1.55*coeff)/coeff);
        System.out.println(Math.round(1.66*coeff)/coeff);
        System.out.println(Math.round(1.75*coeff)/coeff);
        System.out.println(Math.round(1.77*coeff)/coeff);
        System.out.println(Math.round(1.88*coeff)/coeff);
        System.out.println(Math.round(1.99*coeff)/coeff);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1.0
1.25
1.25
1.5
1.5
1.75
1.75
1.75
2.0
2.0
```

Comment: How will it solve both? How does it know which to use? `Math.round (3.8*4)/4f == 3.75`

Comment: @user unk: Because `one half is two quarters` and: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)/

Comment: But `Math.round (3.8*2)/2f == 4.0`, not `3.75`.

Comment: @user: try `(3.8*4)/4f` so your coefficient is 4 instead of using 2. (Not sure coefficient is the right term in this case. Any better term?)

Comment: Yes, but didn't you write 'You don't need to do two different equations for half or quarter rounding.'? What did you mean by that?

Comment: Well, in one place I want 0.74 to be rounded to 0.75. and in another to 0.5. You cant solve both in one equation.

Comment: @user450602: Sorry, I misunderstood that part of the question. Yes, you will need to use two different equations in that case.

Answer (score 5):

`(Math.round(num/toNearest))*toNearest;`

Will round a number to `toNearest`

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically speaking, you could multiply your float by .25, round it, and then divide again by .25.

EDIT: I'm sorry, it seems I misunderstood what you meant by quarter. However, as far as I know, this is the simplest way to round to various decimal places and degrees.

Comment: I think you mean "multiply by 4".